# How can i click button based on text instead of Class

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, if-statement

I can't edit this code to work in buttons based on text instead of class or make it for both by class name and text.

For example:

```
    <button class="same">plz-click-me</button>
    <button class="same">dont-click-me</button>
```

Now I want code to click on the "click-me" button

This what I used in my code to click by class

```
 var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.same:not(.hidden_elem)');
```

Thanks and hope to find answers help me

Comment: you want to select element based on its text ?

Comment: What does "work" mean to you? And, where are the elements with the `._t3` and `.hidden_elem` classes?

Comment: yes exactly this what i need

Comment: You need a loop to check each button whether its `.innerHTML` / `.html()` is `"click-me"`

Comment: @ChrisG Not `.innerHTML` (and certainly not in a loop). `.textContent`. But, instead of even than just get the element based on another criteria.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Are you saying [this](https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/q08d9soz/) won't work? Or are you saying it's bad practice?

Comment: @ChrisG It's bad practice. `.innerHTML` should only ever be used when you are getting/setting strings that contain HTML and you need that HTML to be parsed. There are performance, security, and event functionality issues with it. But, it *can* work and most people aren't aware of these issues so it gets used all over the place where it shouldn't.

Comment: thanks for all .. i edit the code to see the full script on codepen i cant edit the script because i am beginner in js so i hope that i can find help about the code ... https://codepen.io/boda/pen/VGQXem

Comment: thanks for all .. i edit the code to see the full script on codepen i cant edit the script because i am beginner in js so i hope that i can find help about the code ... codepen.io/boda/pen/VGQXem

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to iterate through the possible matching elements and select those whose `textContent` matches what you want. You can't use jQuery's `.contains` because the substring `click-me` is included in `don't-click-me`:

```js
const matching = Array.prototype.filter.call(
  document.querySelectorAll('.same'),
  ({ textContent }) => textContent === 'click-me'
);
console.log(matching);
```

```html
<button class="same">click-me</button>
<button class="same">dont-click-me</button>
```

Note that if the substring of the one you want to select is *not* included in the elements you don't want to select, you *can* use `.contains`:

```js
$('.same:contains("click-this-here")').click(() => console.log('clicked'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="same">click-this-here</button>
<button class="same">dont-click-me</button>
```

Comment: thanks for all .. i edit the code to see the full script on codepen i cant edit the script because i am beginner in js so i hope that i can find help about the code ... https://codepen.io/boda/pen/VGQXem

Comment: thanks for all .. i edit the code to see the full script on codepen i cant edit the script because i am beginner in js so i hope that i can find help about the code ... codepen.io/boda/pen/VGQXem

Answer (score 0):

```js
    var buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");
    var clickButton = Array.from(buttons).filter( button => button.textContent === "click-me")[0];
```

```html
<button class="same">click-me</button>
<button class="same">dont-click-me</button>
```

Comment: `.getElementsByTagName()` returns a live node list. Every time the variable is accessed, the entire document is re-scanned for matching nodes so it has performance implications. Using it with a loop just compounds them. Use `.querySelectorAll()` instead.

Comment: owe i tought getElementsByTagName was better then querySelectorAll in terms of  performances

Comment: Not at all. `.querySelector()` and `.querySelectorAll()` are the newer DOM querying methods. `.getElementsByTagName()`, `.getElementsByName()`, and `.getElementsByClassName()` all return live node lists and suffer from the same issue.

Comment: Now, you just need to complete your answer by showing the OP how a `click` event handler would be set up on the correct button.

Comment: thanks for all .. i edit the code to see the full script on codepen i cant edit the script because i am beginner in js so i hope that i can find help about the code ... https://codepen.io/boda/pen/VGQXem

Comment: thanks for all .. i edit the code to see the full script on codepen i cant edit the script because i am beginner in js so i hope that i can find help about the code ... codepen.io/boda/pen/VGQXem